# django left join and right join implement sqlite

Tags: django, model

I have two tables as shown below :

**country**

```
id name
1  A
2  b
3  c
```

**state**

```
id | country_id | name | population
1  | 1          | x    | 234354
2  | 1          | y    | 2334
3  | 2          | h    | 232323
4  | 2          | E    | 8238787
```

Now I want query with sum population with country name like this :

```
a has xxxx population
b has xxxx population
c has 0 population
```

In *django* query, I have write this query :

```
City.objects.values('country__name').annotate(Sum('population'))
```

But this has not display 0 for c country :(

Comment: `City.objects.exclude(country__isnull=True).values('country__name').annotate(sum=Sum('population')).order_by('-sum')`

Answer (score 0):

The query is not showing any record for c country, because table does not have any record for c country.

```
City.objects.values('country__name').annotate(Sum('population'))
```

This query will show any those records which are there in the City Model.

Comment: any raw query? can we use for this?